# How to find functional dependancies from simply looking at a relational schema?

Tags: database-design, schema, relational-theory

If only given a schema (table header, with primary key indicated), how do I find functional dependencies?

My problem is that functional dependencies are determined in terms of the data stored in the relevant table, and so you could not determine all, but only some functional dependencies by looking at the schema only?

Consider this example:

[image]

How do I go about finding the applicable functional dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell the functional dependencies just from the schema.

If you knew that the schema was in third normal form (3NF) or higher *and* you knew that there are no other candidate keys other than the primary key, then you would know that every non-key attribute was fully functionally dependent on the primary key.

Except for this particular situation, there is nothing about a schema that conveys functional dependency.  The purpose of a schema is to convey table structure, not functional dependencies.

Comment: We still know that `(bday, firstname, lastname) -> email` and `(bday, firstname, lastname) -> street_no` (and all other trivial and derived dependencies), correct? It doesn't matter that we don't know if there are other candidate keys. We still know one key.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It's fair to assume that, at least in a very formal way, if you have a key you can say that non-key elements are determined by that key.  On the other hand, semantically speaking you don't know if the non key attributes are truly functionally dependent on the key.  I'm thinking of a husband and wife who share an email address.  If you know a `bday`, `firstname`, `lastname` you will presumably find _an_ email (if it's mandatory).  Still, wouldn't you want to move email out into its own entity and implement a m:n intersection to avoid potential data change anomalies?